# ¿Hay una forma de hacer mas eficiente este código?

Tags: java

**Hola chic@s, quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de hacer este código mas eficiente, si tienen alguna sugerencia o recomendación lo agradecería mucho.**

"con hacer mas eficiente me refiero a hacerlo mas corto"

```
 public class inicio {
        
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
         int[] Aux1 = new int[] {1,0,0,0,1};
         int[] Aux2 = new int[] {0,1,0,1,0};
         int[] Aux3 = new int[] {0,0,1,0,0};
                 
         int[][] matriz  = new int [5][5];
         
            for(int i = 0; i< matriz.length;i++) {
                 for(int j=0; j<matriz[i].length;j++) {
                    if(i==0 || i== 4){
                        matriz[i]= Aux1;
                    }
                    if(i==1 || i== 3){
                        matriz[i]= Aux2;
                    }
                    if(i==2){
                        matriz[i]= Aux3;
                    }
                 }
            }    
            
             
             for(int i = 0; i< matriz.length;i++) {
                 for(int j=0; j<matriz[i].length;j++) {
                     System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+" ");
                 }
                 System.out.println("");
        }
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leas [ask]

Comment: Que es lo que se supone que hace tu algoritmo

Comment: ¿Estás tratando de llenar las dos diagonales (principal y secundaria ) con 1 ?

Comment: Más eficiente no significa más corto. Hay códigos muy cortos que no son *nada eficientes*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, de esta manera:
Solo se declaran dos variables nuevas, una que `incremente` y otra que `decremente` para obtener la diagonal derecha. Así ya no es necesario usar los demás `arrays`.

```
     int[][] matriz  = new int [5][5];
     int n = 0, m = 4;
     
        for(int i = 0; i< matriz.length;i++) {
             for(int j=0; j<matriz[i].length;j++) {
                
                if(i == j){
                    matriz[i][j] = 1;
                }
                
                if(i == n && j == m){
                    
                    matriz[i][j] = 1;
                    n++;
                    m--;
                }
                
                System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+" ");
             }
             System.out.println("");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Analizando los indices de la diagonal principal

```
    0  1  2  3
0  00
1     11
2        22
3           33
```

entonces solo se necesita un indice: **matriz[ i ][ i ] = 1;**

Para la diagonal secundaria:

```
    0   1   2   3
0              03 
1          12
2      21 
3   30
```

El primero de los indices es i. El segundo decrece desde (m - 1) a 0 por ejemplo con array[4][4] m es 4 => (m-1) = 3. se puede lograr este decrecimiento restando i a (m-1) es decir: **(m-1) - i**

```
i    (m-1) - i = j 
0    (4-1) - 0 = 3  -> [0][3]
1    (4-1) - 1 = 2  -> [1][2]
2    (4-1) - 2 = 1  -> [2][1]
3    (4-1) - 3 = 0  -> [3][0]
```

Funciona **para matrices n X m donde n = m**, los indices para la diagonal secundaria: **matriz[ i ][(m-1)-i] = 1;**.

Una situación a destacar es que cuando la matriz es de número impar ej [5][5], el número del medio (donde se cruzan) se escribe 2 veces lo cual no es un problema en este caso porque ambos son 1, si son valores distintos hay que tener en cuenta ese caso especial.

```
int[][] matriz = new int[9][9]; 
int m = matriz.length-1; // resto 1 a m
for(int i = 0 ; i <= m ; i++) { //ya resté 1 a m
    matriz[i][i] = 1;
    matriz[i][m-i] = 1;
}
```

Se puede adaptar a lo que necesites.

En cuanto a la impresión de la matriz utilice esto para probarlo, no se si es mas "eficiente", un foreach que toma fila a fila, Arrays.toString() que retorna la fila en formato string y replaceAll que elimina los corchetes ([]) y las comas (,) por un espacio en blanco usando una expresión regular

```
for(int[] fila : matriz) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fila).replaceAll("[,|\\[|\\]]", " "));
}
```